# How to change the speed of video playback

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, playback

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the video playback speed in an iphone application. we want users to yell in the microphone to speed up the playback and get to the end.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use setCurrentPlaybackRate:

Answer (score 2):

There is a `rate` property for the `AVPlayer`.

If you take the example from Apple called "avPlayerDemo" in the resource section, you then simply have to set the `mplayer.rate`. It worked for me, I created a new slider in the xib files, implemented that slider in the `AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewController` and simply set `mPlayer.rate` to the slider value.

Comment: I'm wondering about this rate. No matter how low i set it, the video still only plays back at like 30-40%, I wan't even slower playback. Any ideas as to why this rate prop seems to be limited?

Comment: I also wonder about this, seems the range 0.0-0.5 does not work, which is strange since you would think the lower the rate the easier it is for the processor to decode the frame in time.

Comment: "I found that I had to set `_player.rate = 0.25;` after `[_player play];`. Setting before didn't work." - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857409/adjust-avplayer-frame-rate-during-playback

Answer (score 0):

What about the MPMoviePlayerController?

```
setCurrentPlaybackRate
```

Here's some code which does not work at that spot

```
-(IBAction)abspielen:(id)sender 
{
    NSString *titleOfButton = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:titleOfButton ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *movieURL = [ NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

    MPMoviePlayerController *themovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL: movieURL];  
    [themovie play];
    [themovie setCurrentPlaybackRate:2.f];    
    [themovie release];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
    [moviePlayer release];              
}
```