# Adjust AVPlayer Frame Rate During Playback

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

Is there a way to change the rate at which frames are rendered during playback?  I have a couple short 5 second videos that I would like to play at 15, 30, or 60 FPS. This would be an option to the user.

I did find a `frameDuration` property in the `AVVideoComposition` class. But all this did was adjust how many frames rendered per second.

Comment: Did you not just answer your own question here? I am having trouble retrieving the FPS for a streaming video with AVPlayer. Please share your experience if you had success with this one, I would be very grateful.