# iOS AVPlayer: How to slow down a 30fps video to 1fps

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avplayer, frame-rate

I have a 30fps Quicktime .mov of still images I created with AVAssetWriter. (It's only about 10 frames long). I would like the user to be able to slow it down using a UISlider to about 1fps, but when I adjust the AVPlayer .rate property from 1 down to 0, it doesn't get anywhere near 1fps, it just stops playback (because a 0 rate is effectively stopping/pausing it, which makes sense). But how can I slow the player down to about 1fps? I think I'd need to do some math to calculate the actual rate, but that's where I'm stuck. Would it end up being something like 0.000000000000001?

Thanks!

Comment: the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7980256/774691 indicates that any rate setting below 0.2 (or even 0.5) may not result in the playback rate being slowed down as much as @taber wants.  however, setting the rate to a fraction between 0.0 and 1.0 is the way to affect this.

Comment: If rate will indeed not go slow enough, then you will probably need to extract the images from the movie file (you can specify the frame that you want) and then display the resulting image.  You can use a timer to show the next frame, and easily get it back in a seconds time.

Comment: Yeah that's the reason for my question - it's definitely not going slow enough. :( Using a timer is what I was doing before trying AVPlayer, but after letting my timer run for about 3-5 minutes, it slowly brings my phone's free memory down from ~20mb to 3-5mb. (No memory leaks, just seems to be a side effect of using a very fast timer.) Argh, I was hoping AVPlayer would be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was a requirement of mine I would approach this as follows (also suggested by Inafziger in the comments). Use AVAssetReader and roll my own viewer for the images. This would give you precise control using a timer as stated in your comments. Make sure you reuse some preallocated image(s) memory area (you can probably get away with space for a single image). I would probably take a pull approach like CoreAudio. When you need an image pull it from some image buffer manager class which calls AVAssetReaders read function. This way you can have N buffers that will always be available. This may be a little overkill. I do believe AVAssetReader pre decodes some amount of the movie upon initialization. This is why I say you can more than likely just get away with using a single buffer for reading image data into.

From you comment about memory issues. I do believe there are some functions in the AVAssetReader and associated classes that use the create rule.

Comment: Thanks! In the end I stuck with my timer method. After re-creating a super simple test project the "free memory downward spiraling" seemed to stop.