# iOS how to slow down specific duration of video's playback speed

Tags: ios, performance, avfoundation, mode

I want to make part of video slow down while rest of it are normal speed, just like the slow mode video taken by iOS camera. How to do that? I've search AVFoundation but found nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7980463/1142743 and  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2483783/1142743

Comment: These are slowing down the whole video speed, what I want is slow down the speed of **specific time duration** in a video. For example I want to make 10s - 20s slowing down while 0-10 and 20-end playing normal speed.

Comment: You mean I can slow down the speed when the video playing?

Comment: But it can't slow **specific duration** speed of a video, could you please post some code if possible?

Comment: Do you just want to achieve playback or do you want to export the resulting video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only talking about creating this effect during playback (and not exporting it), you should be able to do so by just changing the `rate` property of `AVPlayer` at specific times. Use `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:` to get notified when it's time to change the rate.

```
CMTime interval = CMTimeMake(10, 1);
NSArray *times = @[[NSValue valueWithCMTime:interval]];

_boundaryTimeObserver = [_avPlayer addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:times
                                                 queue:nil
                                            usingBlock:^{
                                                [_weakPlayer setRate:0.5];
                                            }];
```

The rate property works as follows:

```
rate = 0.0; // Stopped
rate = 0.5; // Half speed
rate = 1.0; // Normal speed
```

For slow motion playback, the AVPlayer property `canPlaySlowForward` must be set to true.

Remember to remove the time observer when you're finished with it, and make sure to use an unretained reference to self or to the player within the block in order to avoid retain cycles.

Comment: What if you want to export the video? Trying to capture the realtime edits (speeding up/slowing down).